# Expectation that include ln, how to deal with it?

Tags: probability

I have X~Beta(1/y , 1)
and I need to calculate E(ln(X) ) ... How can I deal with the ln inside the expectation and get the final result?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is beta $(a,1)$, then
$$
E[\log X]=\int_0^1(\log x)f_X(x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^1(\log x)\,ax^{a-1}\mathrm dx=a^{-1}\int_0^1\log u\,\mathrm du.$$
where the last identity stems from the change of variable $u=x^a$. Can you finish?